# How does github calculate the "contribution level" of a given day

Tags: github, statistics

Alright, so I am trying to rework the Github contribution graph feature, and I would like the "level" of contribution to be accurate to Github's. By level I mean the brightness of the square (if you are in darkmode).
[image]

Here in this image you can see a day with a high level and a day with a low level.

For starters, the level is calculated in relation to the other days, however it is unclear how that calculation is being done. On the [Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#contributionlevel) it says that the level is calculated based on which quartile the day falls into.

I don't know much about statistics, but shouldn't there be an equal amount of days in each quartile? But, if you look at this contribution graph, you can clearly see there are many more days with a lower level than there are with a higher level.
[image]

Is there something I am missing? Am I wrong about quartiles? Any help is appreciated.